# QOS rule to In-Home Streaming (Valve SteamLink)

Tags: networking, router

First of all, router's manual is totally useless: https://eu.dlink.com/-/media/product-pages/dva/5592/files/dva5592a1manualv100it.pdf
It's a D-Link DVA-5592 and, being a "partnership" between D-Link and Italian ISP "Infostrada", it's quite difficult to find any info on the net.

What I would like to do is create a QOS rule for traffic coming from the LAN (I could also say directly "from ETH1", but maybe it is useful to have a wider "scope") to a particular host, with static IP, on the 5GHz WiFi network.
This is to do home-streaming from a Windows PC with Steam to a SteamLink connected to the TV.

I'm not sure if this is entirely possible or QOS is only limited to traffic going in/out of WAN interface.

In particular, what I do not understand is the "Interface" section, visible here: [image: DVA-5592]

Starting from the second entry, "Ingress Interface", what does that indicate? Traffic origin or destination?
Among the various interfaces available I have:

- None
- All Interfaces
- Locally Generated Traffic
- PPP and ATM (that do not interest me)
- Wi-Fi (every single network selectable)
- Ethernet (every single port selectable)
- WiFi Ethernet bridge

And why do I have an "Ingress" interface but I also have to specify its type - Ingress/Egress? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: Ingress = inbound packets, egress = outbound packets. The bridge mentioned is internal, because home grade routers are combo devices (router, switch,firewall, WAP) there is a logical bridge inside the device that links all the separate network components together. (It's usually programmable).

Comment: So you're saying I should leave that Bridge as Ingress Interface, right? But what about Type, is it inbound/outbound from where? My WAN?

Comment: You usually don't do anything with ingress, as you have no control over the packets you are receiving through the ISP. You can if you wish, but I doubt it will have any impact on performance. The idea of qos is to make a slight bottleneck on your side. This allows you to have control of the packets on your side of the network that are exiting.

Comment: I would use the wlan/lan bridge as the interface. You would then set the queues from the destination port numbers for the services you want to queue

Comment: Set it like [this](https://i.imgur.com/TowazzY.jpg) and from network tests on SteamLink and actual gameplay it looks like it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Tim's comments, I came up with this solution, which seems to be working fine.
I tested it from actual SteamLink tool (network test) and by playing some games which I used to play in the past days when I had another router and results are satisfying.

[image: QOS Rule]

I chose "DSCP AF33(30)" code by following this pretty neat table - [DSCP](http://www.patrickdenis.biz/blog/ip-precedence-dscp-tos-lookup-table/) - and, as you can see, it refers to High Priority Streaming Video.